# Angular $http.post

Tags: angularjs, post, http-post

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com angularJS e nodeJS, onde tenho que enviar (POST) os dados de um usuário que está se cadastrando. Meu arquivo node server.js é o seguinte:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var authenticationController = require('./server/controllers/authentication-controller.js');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + "/app" ));
app.use('/node_modules',express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules" ))



app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

//Authentication
app.post('/api/user/signup', authenticationController.signup);

app.listen('3000', function (){
    console.log("Listening for Local Host 3000");
});
```

E esse é o código angular responsável por realizar o POST:

```
var myApp = angular.module('votingApp', []);
myApp.controller('signupController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){  
$scope.createUser = function(){
    console.log("teste");
    console.log($scope.user);
    $http.post('api/user/signup', $scope.user).success(function(response){

        }).error(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        console.log("debugMe!");
        })
    }
}]);
```

O controlador 'signupController' está sendo executado corretamente: 'teste' está sendo impresso no console, e também consigo visualizar de forma correta o $scope.user. Mas quando vai executar o $http.post recebo o erro no console 'Cannot POST /url'. Também é impresso 'debugMe!', indicando que deu erro na hora de realizar o POST. Porque não está funcionando?

Answer (score 2):

Nas boas práticas, você nunca deve fazer uma requisição em seu controller, sempre crie um service ou uma factory para isso, seguindo o angular style guide de papa é recomendável tu criar uma factory e chamar ela no controller.

Sua api está esperando receber o user?

Tente chamar assim:

```js
$http({
        url: '/api/user/signup',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'user' : $scope.user }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
    }, 
    function(response) { // optional
            // failed
    });
```